Flask RuntimeError: Working outside of application context - How to resolve?
I'm encountering a RuntimeError in my Flask application, specifically
    RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
                  This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
                  the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
                  with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.

This error occurs even after implementing common solutions such as using app_context() and ensuring proper import statements. I suspect it might be related to circular imports or misconfigured application initialization.
Error Context:
The error occurs when accessing current_app or g within my Flask application. I'm using the Flask framework along with Pony ORM and Redis for database and caching functionalities
Code Structure:
Here's an overview of my project structure:

api/
│
├── run.py                            # Entry point to run the application
├── Backend/                          # Main application package
│   ├── __init__.py                   # Initializes the app
│   ├── app_factory.py                # Contains the create_app function
│   ├── User/
│   │   └── user_route.py             # User routes
│   ├── Service/
│   │   └── service_route.py          # Service routes
│   ├── Category/
│   │   ├── __init__.py               # Initializes the category module
│   │   ├── category_routes.py        # Category routes
│   │   ├── Category_Controller.py    # Category controller logic
│   │   └── Category_Repository.py    # Category repository logic
│   ├── Unit/
│   │   └── unit_route.py             # Unit routes
│   ├── Product/
│   │   └── product_route.py          # Product routes
│   ├── Supplier/
│   │   └── supplier_route.py         # Supplier routes
│   └── Utilities/
│       └── Redis_Client.py           # Redis client utilities
└── __init__.py                       # Top-level package initializer (if needed)


These are the modals
from pony.orm import Database, Required, Optional, PrimaryKey, Set
from datetime import datetime

db = Database()

class Unit(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    products = Set('Product')
    created_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())
    updated_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())

class Category(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    products = Set('Product')
    suppliers = Set('CategorySupplier')
    created_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())
    updated_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())

class Product(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    image_name = Optional(str)
    category = Required(Category)
    unit = Required(Unit)
    expiration_date = Optional(str)
    unit_price = Optional(float)
    stock = Set('Stock')
    inbound_stocks = Set('InboundStock')
    outbound_stocks = Set('OutboundStock')
    clients = Set('ProductClient')
    suppliers = Set('ProductSupplier')
    inventory_audits = Set('InventoryAudit')
    order_items = Set('OrderItem')
    returns = Set('Return')
    created_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())
    updated_date = Optional(datetime, default=lambda: datetime.utcnow())


Despite these efforts, the error persists. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this RuntimeError? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
my run.py file
from Backend import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


my init.py file
from .app_factory import create_app

app = create_app()


my app_factory.py file
from flask import Flask, g,current_app
from flask_cors import CORS
from .User.user_route import user_bp
from .Service.Service_Route import service_bp
from .Category.Category_Route import category_bp  # Make sure this import is correct
from .Category.Category_Controller import CategoryController  # Make sure this import is correct
from .Category.Category_Repository import CategoryRepository  # Make sure this import is correct
from .Unit.Unit_route import unit_bp
from .Product.Product_Route import product_bp
from .Supplier.Supplier_Route import supplier_bp
from .Utilities.Redis_Client import RedisClient
import os
from pony.flask import Pony


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    Pony(app)
    app.config.update(dict(
        DEBUG=True,
        SECRET_KEY=os.urandom(24),
    ))

    # Initialize Redis client and Category repository
    redis_client = RedisClient()
    category_repository = CategoryRepository()

    # Initialize the Category controller with dependencies
    category_controller = CategoryController(category_repository, redis_client)

    @app.before_request
    def before_request():
        g.category_controller = category_controller
        print(f"Current app name: {current_app.name}")  # Debugging print

    CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
    app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

    # Register blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(user_bp, url_prefix='/User')
    app.register_blueprint(service_bp, url_prefix='/Service')
    app.register_blueprint(category_bp, url_prefix='/Category')
    app.register_blueprint(unit_bp, url_prefix='/Unit')
    app.register_blueprint(product_bp, url_prefix='/Product')
    app.register_blueprint(supplier_bp, url_prefix='/Supplier')

    return app


my Categor_Route file
from flask import Blueprint, g, jsonify

category_bp = Blueprint('Category', __name__)


@category_bp.before_app_request
def load_controller():
    g.category_controller = g.get('category_controller', None)


@category_bp.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    if g.category_controller:
        return g.category_controller.create_category()
    return jsonify({'error': 'Controller not found'}), 500


@category_bp.route('/delete/<int:id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete(id: int):
    if g.category_controller:
        return g.category_controller.delete_category(id)
    return jsonify({'error': 'Controller not found'}), 500


@category_bp.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['PUT'])
def update(id):
    if g.category_controller:
        return g.category_controller.update_category(id)
    return jsonify({'error': 'Controller not found'}), 500


@category_bp.route('/list', methods=['GET'])
def list_categories():
    if g.category_controller:
        return g.category_controller.list_category()
    return jsonify({'error': 'Controller not found'}), 500


@category_bp.route('/list/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def list_category_by_id(id: int):
    if g.category_controller:
        return g.category_controller.list_category_by_id(id)
    return jsonify({'error': 'Controller not found'}), 500


my Category_controller file
from flask import *
from .Category_Repository import CategoryRepository
from ..Utilities.DTO import JSONResponse
from ..Utilities.SearchAlgorithms import SearchAlgorithms


class CategoryController:

    def __init__(self, category_repository: CategoryRepository, search_algorithms: SearchAlgorithms):
        self.category_repository = category_repository
        self.redis_client = current_app.config['REDIS_CLIENT']
        self.categories = None
        self.category = None
        self.search_algorithms = search_algorithms

    def create_category(self) -> JSONResponse:
        data = request.get_json()
        name: str = data.get('name')
        if not data:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No data was Found'}), 404
        try:
            self.category_repository.add(name)
            self.categories = self.category_repository.get_all()
            self.redis_client.set('categories', self.categories)
            return jsonify({'message': 'Category created'}), 201
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 400

    def delete_category(self, category_id: int) -> JSONResponse:
        try:

            if self.category_repository.get(category_id):
                self.category_repository.delete(category_id)
                self.categories = self.category_repository.get_all()
                self.redis_client.set('categories', self.categories)
                return jsonify({'message': 'Category deleted'}), 200
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

    def update_category(self, category_id: int) -> JSONResponse:
        data = request.get_json()
        if not data:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No data was found'}), 400
        try:
            category = self.category_repository.get(category_id)
            if not category:
                return jsonify({'error': 'Category not found'}), 404
            self.category_repository.update(category_id, data.get('name'))
            self.categories = self.category_repository.get_all()
            self.redis_client.set('categories', self.categories)
            return jsonify({'message': category.to_dict()}), 200
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

    def list_category(self) -> JSONResponse:
        category = self.redis_client.get('categories')
        if not category:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No category found'}), 404
        return jsonify({'list': category}), 200

    def list_category_by_category_id(self, category_id: int) -> JSONResponse:
        self.categories = self.redis_client.get('categories')
        self.category = self.search_algorithms.binary_search(self.categories, category_id)
        if not self.category:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Category not found'}), 404
        return jsonify({'list': self.category.to_dict()}), 200


my Category_Repository file
from pony.orm import *


class CategoryRepository:
    @db_session
    def add(self, name: str):
        Category(name=name)

    @db_session
    def get(self, category_id: int):
        return Category.get(id=category_id)

    @db_session
    def get_all(self):
        category = [s.to_dict() for s in Category.select()]
        return category

    @db_session
    def update(self, category_id: int, name: str):
        category = Category.get(id=category_id)
        if category:
            if name:
                category.name = name

    @db_session
    def delete(self, category_id: int):
        category = Category.get(id=category_id)
        if category:
            Category.delete(id=category_id)```


Maybe in your app_factory.py in create_app function add with app.app_context like so :
def create_app():     app = Flask(__name__)     with app.app_context():         Pony(app)

Thank you after checking the doc and exploring similar issues i was able to solve the prolem the exact way you mentioned  i had to add with app.app_context at the top of create_app function

Great, you can still write an answer to your question.. and accept it..so it becomes answered and closed and others who seek help in future can have clues when facing something similar
